# How do I know if the company is good when all companies have negative reviews?

Tags: job-search

I'm exploring potential employers and one common pattern I get it that on Glassdoor, no matter which company I look for, they all have some negative reviews, some conflicting reviews (for eg, work-life balance appears in pros as well as cons), and someone suggesting to stay away from the company.

When you have a friend working in one of those companies it becomes easier but when a company is entirely new for you, how do you get an idea of the company as an employer?

Comment: More negative cf least negative...

Comment: How do you know if a restaurant is good? It has both good and bad reviews. Read the reviews and make a judgment based on your gut feelings and intuition. There's no way to know it the company is good or bad from someone else's subjective opinion.

Comment: @joeqwerty It's easier to try out a restaurant than a company. Even if you include the interview as part of trying out the company (as you should), that takes a lot more effort/preparation than trying out a new a restaurant.

Comment: Don't forget to consider the department in question inside the company. A marketing person may have a great work-to-life balance, but a software engineer may have none. This kind of thing really varies by department.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The key question is whether a company is good *for you***

Is a company that provides little flexibility a good or bad thing?

I would consider it bad, because I do lots of things outside work that enrich my life and career and losing those would be a negative for me. I have a good friend who considers it a major benefit as he doesn't need it and wants highly disciplined co-workers. Neither answer is correct. It depends on your own preferences.

On work-life balance though, we are the opposite. I am happy to log in at 1AM on Saturday if you need me and in my company, it is not unusual (certainly not required or encouraged, but some people enjoy their work) to see commits at midnight on any given day of the week. That same friend would hate that expectation.  **He wants work out of his life over the weekend, with clear delineations between work and life. I am fine if it weaves in and out. Again, neither is wrong. Just a preference.**

**Even with disgruntled employees, there is often a lot of truth to their comments.** Reading the comments about my former employers, I wouldn't call many of them untruthful. Biased and/or exaggerated yes, but not untruthful.

For example, at a former employer of mine there is a complaint that things constantly changed on a whim based on high level management. I would consider that accurate if you prefer consultation over command, as it was very top down. There is another complaint about there being little new development and no room for advancement, with people staying for a long time in their roles. I would also consider this true, if you are a person who prioritizes advancement. If you prefer stability, that is actually a positive. **Focus on whether you see what the person is complaining about as a positive or negative.**

You also have to remember that **in plenty of companies, teams are little fiefdoms**, run however that particular manager runs their team. At one of my internships, there were two groups in the same department. One group was run by someone I respected, but would have been frustrated working for because they had a very involved managerial style. I was in the group where things were very laid back. I could have had the same job, but **my experience (and review) would have been enormously different if I had that manager over the one I had.** But her team nearly universally loved her.

**TL;DR: Read the reviews and see whether you specifically object to what the person is complaining about. "Negative" for them may be positive for you. Also remember that managers differ and they can make or break your experience at a company.**

Comment: This is the best advice possible.  The same goes for when your company merges or acquired.  It's all about if it's good or bad for you.

Answer (score 2):

> when a company is entirely new for you, how do you get an idea of the
> company as an employer?

When I'm working through an external recruiter, I've found that a conversation with them can often yield clues as to whether a company would be a good fit for me or not.

With or without recruiter input, when I interview I always ask to talk with one or more of my potential peers (and when it's a management role, I ask to talk to as many of the folks who would be on my team as possible.) I have found that peers are often more open during an interview than others might be. I ask them what it is like to work for the hiring manager, what it is like to work on that team, and what it is like to work for that company.

If I sense any red flags, I dig in with more pointed questions. I might ask why they are recruiting for a position externally, rather than promoting internally. I might ask about the team's turnover. I often ask what they like most and what they like least. If I were very concerned about work-life balance, I'd ask about that.

Talking with directly involved people face-to-face is always better than reading faceless, anonymous reviews from potentially disgruntled ex-employees.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the already published good answer: don't underestimate the reviews. The trick is to read them not one-dimentionally (good-bad), but as signalling the company's culture and values.

I work for a large, non-IT company. The reviews from IT people repeat expressions such as:

> extremely chaotic

> IT jobs don't have anything to do with what was in the job description since basic technological prerequisites are missing

All that is true. If I had known that before, I would have steered away from the company and saved myself a lot of frustration.